# Binomial identities based on Vandermonde

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I am solving exercise 5.14 from *Concrete Mathematics* which demands the identities
$$\sum_{k=0}^l(-1)^k\binom{l-k}{m}\binom{s}{k-n}=(-1)^{l+m}\binom{s-m-1}{l-m-n},\quad l,m,n\in\mathbb N, s\in\mathbb C,$$
and
$$\sum_{k=0}^l\binom{l-k}{m}\binom{q+k}{n}=\binom{l+q+1}{m+n+1},\quad l,m,n,q\in\mathbb N,n\geq q$$
to be proven.

Using upper negation and Vandermonde's convolution, I was able to prove the first identity.

However, I'm having difficulties with the second one. Apparently, it is doable starting from the first identity, then replacing $s$ by $-1-n-q$ and then applying the upper negation formula again.

I started from the first formula and

- applied upper negation and symmetry onto $\binom{s}{k-n}$ and $\binom{s-m-1}{l-m-n}$, and
- executed the suggested replacement.

I end up with
$$\sum_{k=0}^l\binom{l-k}{m}\binom{q+k}{q+n}=\binom{l+q+1}{m+n+q+1}.$$

Similar, but not the same... Any tips on how to continue or proceed differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now do a change of variables to replace $n$ with $n-q \ge 0$.

Comment: I feel silly now. Thank you.